# Typescript type definitions for elasticsearch-browser

Tags: angular, typescript, elasticsearch

I was attempting to use the JS library for elasticsearch in an Angular application.   The library imported with no problem:

```
npm install elasticsearch
npm install @types/elasticsearch
```

And then the IDE could recognize the types for the API.   However it would not work in the browser.   Instead I had to use

```
npm install elasticsearch-browser
```

This works and now the API works but there is no `@types/elasticsearch` to install.  I can proceed with development but it really helps to have the
IDE check my code.   Does anyone know if there is a type-definition out there somewhere?

A possible work-around is to somehow import the `@types/elasticsearch` definitions and use them for the `elasticsearch-browser` package.  But I don't know how to do that.  Any help?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's the right way, but this worked for me:

elasticsearch.d.ts:

```
declare module "elasticsearch-browser" {
  import elasticsearch from "elasticsearch";
  import "elasticsearch-browser";
  export * from "elasticsearch";
}
```

Then `import elasticsearch from "elasticsearch-browser"` anywhere you need to use it.

Comment: You've saved my day. For new client lib, just change `import elasticsearch from "elasticsearch";` to `import "@elastic/elasticsearch";` and `export * from "elasticsearch";` to `export * from "@elastic/elasticsearch";`.

Comment: @pootow which folder should the elasticsearch.d.ts be located? I just can't get elastic working in Angular. if you happen to have a small sample I'd be ever so grateful.